# std::tuple default constructor with move-constructable element

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I'm trying to return a `std::tuple` containing an element that is a non-copy-constructable type. This seems to prevent me from using the default class constructor to construct the tuple. For example, to return a tuple containing `Foo`, a `foo` instance must be created and `std::move`d:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    int x;
};

tuple<int, Foo> MakeFoo() {
    Foo foo{37};
//  return {42, {37}}; // error: could not convert ‘{42, {37}}’ from ‘’ to ‘std::tuple’
    return {42, std::move(foo)};
}
```

On the other hand, if the class is defined to have a copy constructor, construction of the tuple works fine:

```
class Bar {
  public:
    Bar(const Bar&) = default;
    int x;
};

tuple<int, Bar> MakeBar() {
    return {42, {37}}; // compiles ok
}
```

**Is there a way to use the `MakeBar` syntax with the `Foo` class?**

Comment: What about `return {42, Foo{37}};`?

Comment: @super that's an improvement, but I'd still like to understand why the compiler can't infer that usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but you have (at least) two options.

You could either spell out the `Foo`:

```
tuple<int, Foo> MakeFoo() {
    return {42, Foo{37}}
}
```

Or you could add a constructor to `Foo` that replaces the aggregate initialization you're now doing:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {}      // <--
    int x;
};

tuple<int, Foo> MakeFoo() {
    return {42, 37};
}
```

But why write `return {42, 37}` instead of `return {42, {37}}`? And why is adding a constructor needed to make this work?

Constructing a tuple with at least one move-only type means we can't use the direct constructor

```
tuple<Types...>::tuple(const Types &...)
```

Instead, we have to use the templated converting constructor

```
template<class... UTypes>
tuple<Types...>::tuple(UTypes &&...)
```

So the types of the two arguments will be deduced. But, `{37}` is an initializer list, which in this case makes the second function parameter a *non-deduced context* (see [[temp.deduct.type]/5.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.6)). So template argument deduction fails, and the constructor cannot be invoked. So, we have to write `return {42, 37}` instead to allow deduction to succeed.

Additionally, this templated converting constructor only participates in overload resolution when the argument types are *convertible* to the respective tuple element types. And convertibility does not consider aggregate initialization, so an `int` is not convertible to the original `Foo`. But if we add the converting constructor `Foo::Foo(int)`, `int` is now convertible to `Foo`, and the `tuple` constructor can be invoked.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case `Foo` is defined in generated code and cannot be easily modified.