# Why is there still no move-from-elements ctor for `std::tuple'?

Tags: c++, tuples, std, stdtuple, isocpp

Long while ago I faced a question very much like this one:

[std::tuple default constructor with move-constructable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58614694/stdtuple-default-constructor-with-move-constructable-element)

C++ is evolving and improving at a high rate, but minor changes to code still bite a programmers toes. I tested adding a SFINAE opted ctor for exact match move-from-elements ctor and just put the problem away.
Now a flashback took me to the problem again.
`std::tuple` just declares 26 (=13*2) [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple). I wonder why it is still lacking one for exact match move from elements? The pair <2,15> define exact match copy from elements. This pair defeats the pair<3,16> overloads (generic make from universal reference list). A move from counterpart does not seem that difficult. SFINAE has become a lot simpler with concepts finally shipping:

```
template<typename ... Types>
tuple<Types ...>::tuple(Types&&... args)
requires(!(is_lvalue_reference_v<Types>&&...&&true));

template<typename Alloc, typename ... Types>
tuple<Types ...>::tuple( std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc&, Types&&... args)
requires(!(is_lvalue_reference_v<Types>&&...&&true));
```

The SFINAE just prevents a duplicate definition for copy-from-elements counterparts, in case all elements are rvalue references; otherwise - if at least one value or rvalue reference element exists - a new pair of constructors will be available. Has there been any other specific reason preventing this pair of constructors from being declared?

Here is the snippet that exemplifies the point:

```
struct A{
        A()=default;
        A(A&&){endl(std::cout<<"A(A&&)");};
        A(A const&){endl(std::cout<<"A(A const&)");};
    };
    struct B{
        B()=default;
        B(B&&){endl(std::cout<<"B(B&&)");};
        B(B const&){endl(std::cout<<"B(B const&)");};
    };
    struct C{
        C()=default;
        C(C&&){endl(std::cout<<"C(C&&)");};
        C(C const&){endl(std::cout<<"C(C const&)");};
    };

std::tuple<A,B,C> abc={{},{},{}};
```

The output is the signature of copy ctors of the classes. Because none-templated ctor#2 is prefered over ctor#3. Now if either of the copy ctors of classes is commented out(`=delete`d), the code just fails to compile; because ctor#3 is `explicit` as it should be. While the proposed new constructors should be only conditionally `explicit`(if either element is explicitly moveable).

Comment: I don't understand your question. what you actually  want to achieve that cannot be done?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. There are move constructors. Is there a specific scenario where they don't get the job done properly?

Comment: Signature (3) uses universal references covering using move constructors for every element among other things...

Comment: 2 is preferred over 3; because 2 is none-template, while 3 is template. Whoever voted to close must have missed the point.

Comment: This sounds like a scenario that nobody thought about when applying concepts to C++20's standard library.

Comment: The snippet does not compile at all, much less calls any constructors.

Comment: -Nicol Bolas long ago, I even tried the SFINEA with an extra `enable_if` arg with default value on VS who was traditionally not SFINEA friendly, and it worked. With concepts, it just looks simpler and more native (less alian).

Comment: -n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. it is not complete code. Minor typos may exist too.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1czn5M853 Don't post code with "minor typos". Compile, *then* copy the *entire* code and paste, *do not edit*, do not post fragments.

Comment: Voting to close as [not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/G37rq5zff).

Comment: I don't. **You** need to post a [mcve].

Comment: Your code is missing default constructors. Once those are provided, "`A(A&&)`" "`B(B&&)`" and "`C(C&&)`" are printed, contrary to what you've asserted.

Comment: Use `@username` to reply, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.   And everybody. A rewrite of the post is ready.

Comment: @jjramsey you made me rethink and dive into more depth

Comment: #3 is not viable because template parameters cannot be deduced.

Comment: `{}` doesn't have a type

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. exactly. Because the proper ctor is missing.

Comment: @Caleth in that case compiler matches it against initializer list. But that is irrelevant. Compiler always tries to deduce a type for curly braces. I guess `std::tuple` should've 28 ctors instead of 28.