# Rules for move when constructing a tuple by return

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics

I have the following c++ example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cEcfodMsv)) that constructs a tuple of `MyStruct` in the functions `foo` and `bar`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct() = default;
    MyStruct(const MyStruct&) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
        
    }
    MyStruct(MyStruct&&) noexcept  {
        std::cout << "Move constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
    ~MyStruct() = default;

    MyStruct& operator=(const MyStruct&) = default;
    MyStruct& operator=(MyStruct&&) noexcept = default;
};

std::tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct> foo() {
    return {MyStruct{}, MyStruct{}};
}

std::tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct> bar() {
    return {{}, {}};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
    auto [a, b] = foo();

    std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
    auto [c, d] = bar();
    return 0;
}
```

And produces the following output:

```
Foo
Move constructor called
Move constructor called
Bar
Copy constructor called
Copy constructor called
```

When I put this code in [c++ insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/ebde5436), it creates the same function for both `foo` and `bar`. So, my understanding is that both foo and bar should move the object instead of bar copying it. **Does anyone know why the behaviour is different?**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58614694/4005637) question is similar but it's not the same as I'm wondering why `bar` copies the value instead of moving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cppinsights.io is wrong here, and doesn't produce code that has the same semantics as your original.
The reason why `return {{}, {}}` calls the copy constructor is a combination of `std::tuple`'s weird constructors, and overload resolution. There are two important constructors here:

```cpp
tuple( const Types&... args ); // (2)

template< class... UTypes >
tuple( UTypes&&... args ); // (3)
```

In both of your return-statements, you are returning prvalues, making (3) a better match because the conversion sequence is shorter (no `const` added).
If possible, this perfect forwarding overload is going to be chosen, and the move constructor is called.

However, this is not possible for `{{}, {}}`, because the types in the `Utypes` pack cannot be inferred from `{}`. In general, you can only use these brace expressions in a context where the type can be inferred.
For example:

```cpp
void take_int(int);
void take_any(auto);

int main() {
    take_int({}); // OK, value initialization of an int
    take_any({}); // ill-formed, cannot infer type from {}
}
```

As a consequence, `{{}, {}}` will use the first constructor, which involves copy construction.
We can reproduce this issue like this:

```cpp
template <typename ...Ts>
struct tuple {
    tuple(const Ts&...);

    template <typename ...Us>
    tuple(Us&&...);
};

struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct() = default;
    MyStruct(const MyStruct&);
    MyStruct(MyStruct&&) noexcept;
};

tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct> foo() {
    return {MyStruct{}, MyStruct{}};
}

tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct> bar() {
    return {{}, {}};
}
```

This code compiles to:

```py
foo():
    # ...
    call tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct>::tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct>(MyStruct&&, MyStruct&&)@PLT
    # ...
    ret
bar():
    # ...
    call tuple<MyStruct, MyStruct>::tuple(MyStruct const&, MyStruct const&)@PLT
    # ...
    ret
```

*See [live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9bo9fW9hT)*